# Should I use past simple or present perfect simple to answer this question?

Tags: tense

I am wondering which tense usage is correct to answer this question.

- How far back has the action shifted?

> The action has shifted to a time before Beloved **has made** her first appearance and before the schoolteacher **has come** to bring Sethe back to Sweet Home.

OR

> The action has shifted to a time before Beloved **made** her first appearance and before the schoolteacher **came** to bring Sethe back to Sweet Home.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I guess both are correct. The first one might be better for consistency.

Comment: When speaking of a work of art, we conventionally use the present. "The action *shifts*...." and so there has to be some reason why you're using "has shifted" here; more context is required. We'd need a sentence or two *preceding* the snippet you've provided.  We might even expect to see "The action has shifted to a time before Beloved *makes* her first appearance..."

Answer (score 1):

> The action has shifted to a time before Beloved has made her first appearance and before the schoolteacher has come to bring Sethe back to Sweet Home.
>
> The action has shifted to a time before Beloved made her first appearance and before the schoolteacher came to bring Sethe back to Sweet Home.

This feels like someone given directions in a script or a screenplay or something similar, and so it's an unusual syntax not often seen outside of that context.

The first sentence is fine, but for clarity I would just use the simple present tense:  "The action has shifted to a time before Beloved **makes** her first appearance and before the schoolteacher **comes** to bring Sethe back to Sweet Home."

Answer (score 0):

> The action has shifted to a time before ...

The verb is being used in the *Present Perfect* tense. In general *Verb-Tense-Agreement* scenarios, when the main clause is Present Perfect, you continue with this tense to show another action *related in time*, or you switch to Past Tense so show a prior action.

The sequence of events listed *does qualify* as being *Related In Time*, so you would stick with the Present Perfect.

If that does not make any sense, then here is The Short Version: Stick with *Has + Past Tense Verb*.